# Confusion over definition of natural numbers

Tags: definition, natural-numbers

In my course we have been given the following definition of the natural numbers

> The natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ are the smallest set such that
>
> 1. $0\in\mathbb{N}$
> 2. if $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then $n+1\in\mathbb{N}$

Surely the rational numbers also satisfy this definition. They are the same size as $\mathbb{N}$, have $0\in\mathbb{Q}$ and we can take any $n\in\mathbb{Q}$ and have $n+1\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Is the definition not as rigorous as it could be or are the naturals the smallest set to satisify the definition and I'm using ideas about cardinality incorrectly?

Comment: "Smallest" here means that if $S$ has the two properties, then $\mathbb{N}\subset S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notion of “smallest set” has nothing to do with cardinality. It refers to *set inclusion*. No proper subset of the naturals as defined here will satisfy the two conditions.

Answer (score 0):

$ 0\in \Bbb N $ and $ 0 $ is the smallest element. There is no element $ n\in \Bbb N $ such that $ n+1=0 $, and this is not true in $ \Bbb Q$.